# WooCommerce: Replace price of productvariation by productattribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

i'm looking for a snippet that gives me the option of replacing the price with the text "Price on request" for a product variant from WooCommerce that already exists.

I'm not a developer or anything like that.
I tried to make something out of different snippets but nada.

On [businessbloomer.com](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-replace-variable-price-with-variation-price/) i found the following snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'bbloomer_update_price_with_variation_price' );
  
function bbloomer_update_price_with_variation_price() {
   global $product;
   $price = $product->get_price_html();
   wc_enqueue_js( "      
      $(document).on('found_variation', 'form.cart', function( event, variation ) {   
         if(variation.price_html) $('.summary > p.price').html(variation.price_html);
         $('.woocommerce-variation-price').hide();
      });
      $(document).on('hide_variation', 'form.cart', function( event, variation ) {   
         $('.summary > p.price').html('" . $price . "');
      });
   " );
}
```

Then I searched for the hook for product attributes and found this: $product_attributes

But as already mentioned, I can't get it together

Would be cool if someone could help me.I